# Enviar correo con informacion del formulario PHP

Tags: php, formularios, email

estoy haciendo una pagina web, quiero que el formulario de contacto envié la información al correo de la empresa, con el código que tengo no me envía la informacion, la envia a un tal webmaster@correodelaempresa.com Y la copia del mensaje me la envia a mi y al que ha rellenado el formulario.

Os dejo aqui mi codigo.

HTML:

```
<form class="formcont" action="" method="post" name="contacto">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <label for="name">Nombre *</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" size="50" maxlength="100" name="nombre" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <label for="email">Email *</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern=".+@.+.com" name="email" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <label for="empresa">Empresa *</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="empresa" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <label for="telefono">Teléfono</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" pattern="/^-?\d+\.?\d*$/" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==9) return false;" maxlength="9" name="telefono">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="textarea">¿Tienes alguna consulta?</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" rows="5" name="mensaje" required></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="textcenter">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="KEY" data-callback="recaptchaCallback"></div>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" class="formsub" id="">
              </div>
            </form>
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $to = $_POST['email'];
                $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
                // $email = $_POST['email'];
                $from = "estialmi08@gmail.com";
                $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
                $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
                $subject = "Mensaje del formulario";
                $subject2 = "Copia del Mensaje del formulario";
                $mensaje = $nombre . " " . $empresa . " Escribió:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['mensaje'];
                $mensaje2 = "Aquí tienes una copia del mensaje " . $nombre . "\n\n" . $_POST['mensaje'];

                $headers = "From:" . $from;
                $headers2 = "To:" . $to;
                mail($to,$subject,$mensaje,$headers);
                mail($from,$subject2,$mensaje2,$headers2);
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo no hacerlo así por motivos de seguridad, piensa que todo aquello que escriba el usuario, es potencialmente peligroso, debes asegurarte que no introduce código maligno, por ejemplo, los bots spamers, pillarán tu form y lo usarán sin duda para hacer spam. Mejor usa una solución ya hecha con todas las protecciones implementadas, claro, puedes hacerlo tu, pero una solución madura siempre será mucho mejor. Otra cosa sería que lo usaras para aprender, pero en un entorno de producción para una empresa, la seguridad prima.

Comment: Te recomendaría usar alguna librería externa tipo PHPMailer Con esta librería puedes crearte una plantilla HTML, para formatear el correo como quieras y mostrar de esta manera los datos del formulario de la forma que quieras

Answer (score 0):

En este fragmento de código quita el pattern. y reemplaza el type="text" por type="email"

```
   <div class="col">
   <label for="email">Email *</label>,
   <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" 
   required>
    </div>
```

Luego verifica o evalúa que te está llegando en $_POST["email"] al llenar el formulario con un condicional:

```
 if(isset($_POST["email"]){
echo "ha llegado un dato";
}
```